# first_name and last_name not saving in custom Django_Registration form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, django-registration

I am having trouble getting the first_name and last_name variables to save once the user has submitted the form. Here is my code.I need help.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class MyRegistration(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, unique = True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, unique = True)

def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name
```

**Forms.py**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import MyRegistration
from django import forms

class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyRegistration


RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(MyRegistrationForm.base_fields)

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
   def save(self, profile_callback = None):
     user = super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).save(profile_callback = None)
     org, c = MyRegistration.objects.get_or_create(user=user, first_name =   
     self.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name'])
```

**In root urls.py**

```
   url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register', {'form_class':         
   CustomRegistrationForm, 'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'}),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very odd way to go about this and there seems to be some crossed wires. Firstly, if you are looking to save some extra data about users, it shouldn't be done via a registration model - you should create a `profile` application that handles extra data. The django docs [have some good suggestions on how to go about this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

More importantly, the default `User` object that you are more then likely creating for your users already has fields for `first_name` and `last_name` so you can use them instead of creating a new profile model