# Additional fields not saving with Django-Registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I have been pulling my hair out for a couple of days trying to get additional fields such as first name and last name to save with Django Registration. I am getting the form fields to show up but after I submit the form, the additional fields don't save.  Please help me.  Thank you!

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
   if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from MyRegistration.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
     first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First Name'), max_length=30, required=True)
     last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last Name'), max_length=30)
```

**Regbackend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from MyRegistration.forms import UserRegistrationForm
from MyRegistration.models import UserProfile


def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):        
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    data = Profile(user=user)
    data.first_name = form.data['first_name']
    data.last_name = form.data['last_name']
    data.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered         
user_registered.connect(user_created, sender = UserProfile)
```

**Urls(root).py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from MyRegistration.forms import UserRegistrationForm
from registration.views import register
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls
import MyRegistration.regbackend


urlpatterns = patterns('',

  url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend':     
     'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm},       
      name='registration_register'),
      (r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [first_name and last_name not saving in custom Django_Registration form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057856/first-name-and-last-name-not-saving-in-custom-django-registration-form)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think you need to go back and look at how django works. You seem to be connecting your own view (in the misnamed `Regbackend.py` file) to the registration signal, creating a new Profile object. Another signal then fires when the User is saved, creating another Profile object. It's very difficult to help out with so many things going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles trying to save extra stuff using the signal.

What I do is get the DefaultBackend of django-registration, copy it into my project, and add there the code to save the extra fields.

Then in urls.py I tell "^accounts/register/$" to use my personalized backend.

Answer (score 0):

Nice. This works okay. I did it this way:

```
def register(self, request, **kwargs):

    ......
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site)

   # This is my additional block
    new_user.first_name = kwargs['first_name']
    new_user.last_name = kwargs['last_name']
    new_user.save()

    data = UserProfile(user=new_user)
    data.gender = kwargs['gender']
    data.address1 = kwargs['address1']
    data.address2 = kwargs['address2']
    data.city = kwargs['city']
    data.state = kwargs['state']
    data.pincode = kwargs['pincode']
    data.save()
    # end of my block. The line below, which didn't work, was 
    # actually replaced by the above code. Ugly but works

    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.